# Wie kann man wissen, ob ein Verb trennbar ist?

Tags: separable-verb

Gibt es eine bewährte Regel für Nicht-Muttersprachler, um zu entscheiden, ob ein Verb trennbar ist?

Comment: Gibt es eigentlich ein Mnemotechnik, um sich die untrennbare Präfix zu merken? Ich glaube, dass ich so eine in die Schule gelernt habe, aber ich kann mich nicht daran erinnern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Es gilt folgende „Regel“: Ist die erste Silbe betont, ist das Verb trennbar.

Leider sagt die Regel allein nicht viel aus. Es wird aber recht gut in dem [Beitrag](http://www.deutschakademie.de/online-deutschkurs/forum/index.php?topic=87.0), aus dem ich die Regel zitiert habe, erklärt:

> Machen beide Wortteile Sinn (sie sind also im Wörterbuch so zu finden), ist das Verb trennbar: aufstehen (auf+stehen), einkaufen (ein+kaufen), absagen (ab+sagen),... Meist ist der 1. Teil eine Präpsition.
>
> Macht aber ein Wortteil keinen Sinn (es ist also nicht im Wörterbuch allein zu finden), ist es nicht trennbar: beginnen (be+ginnen [machen beide keinen Sinn]), vergessen (ver+gessen [machen beide keinen Sinn]), zertrennen (zer+trennen [„zer“ macht keinen Sinn]). **Ausnahme** sind Verben mit „er“ – die sind auch **nicht** trennbar.
>
> Aufpassen musst du bitte auch bei Verben mit „unter“ und „über“: Die sind manchmal trennbar, manchmal nicht: „Das Boot geht im Wasser unter.“ „Bitte unterschreiben Sie hier.“ Da muss man alle Verben extra lernen

Ich hoffe, das hilft dir weiter.

Answer (score 8):

Um die Sache ein bisschen zu vereinfachern, hier eine Liste für dich:

- be, zer, ver, ent, emp, ge, er, hinter, ....,  sind untrennbar
- ab, an, ein, aus, auf, los, mit, bei, dar, ....,  sind trennbar
- durch, über, um, unter  sind manchmal trennbar, manchmal auch nicht, und hier hilft uns besonders die "Betonungsregel"

die Liste könnte man ergänzen, aber die oben erwähnten Präfixen sieht man am häufigsten, also habe ich nur diese aufgelistet.

Comment: Danke! Sind die (un)trennbare immer (un)trennbare, oder gibt es Ausnahmen?

Comment: ich glaube da sind keine Ausnahmen --- aber bin mir nicht 100% sicher (z.B. in der Umgangssprache könnte es welche geben)

Comment: Das ist eine sehr schlechte Nachricht für Natural Language Processing Software (NLP), wenn man zum Verständnis auf die Betonung angewiesen ist.

Answer (score 6):

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/V-To-V/Praefig.html?country=D) hat eine gute Übersicht mit den Präfixen für [trennbare und untrennbare Verben](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Trennbare-0n.html).

Besonders interessant fand ich das Beispiel mit `umfahren`:

```
1. untrennbar:   umfáhren     Der Bus umfährt die Baustelle.
2. trennbar:     úmfahren     Der Bus fährt einen Hydranten um.
```

In solchen Momenten bin ich immer froh, dass ich Deutsch nicht als Fremdsprache lernen muss.

[Liste mit 9185 Beispielen für trennbare Verben](http://canoonet.eu/services/InflectionRules/Controller?entryClass=Cat%20V&inflectionClass=Trennbare%20Verben&resultId=1719c59)

Answer (score 0):

Hier hilft nur ein gutes Wörterbuch, denn zu allem anderen kommt, dass die Unterscheidung trennbar oder nicht trennbar nicht allein aus den Bestandteilen abzuleiten ist, sondern auch noch zeitlichem Wandel unterliegen kann. So heißt es in Meyers Konversationslexikon von 1885-1892 [hier](https://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=104238):

> Der Schwerpunkt des Reichs lag im Reichstag, der seit 1653 in Regensburg versammelt war. Ihm **lagen** die Gesetzgebung, Kriegsverfassung, Steuerbewilligung u. a. **ob**.

Das würde heute praktisch niemand mehr trennen.