# Welche deutschen Wörter unterscheiden sich nur in der Betonung?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, stress

Generell gibt es im Deutschen, wie auch in anderen verwandten Sprachen, kaum Beispiele für Wörter, deren Bedeutung sich ändert, wenn man nur die Betonung variiert. In anderen Sprachen kommt dies häufiger vor. Als Beispiel, dass die Betonung auch im Deutschen eine Rolle für die Bedeutung von Wörtern hat, kenn ich nur *umfahren* – initial betont bedeutet es quasi das genaue Gegenteil zur Betonung auf der mittleren Silbe. Welche anderen Beispiele für dieses Phänomen gibt es?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wörter mit gleicher Schreibweise und unterschiedlichem Betonung nennt man *Homographe*.

Davon gibt es im Deutschen einige, zum Beispiel *modern,* das je nach Betonung (modérn) entweder *neumodisch* oder den Vorgang des Verwesens (módern) bezeichnet.

Wikipedia hat eine [Liste](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym#2.1._Beispiele_f.C3.BCr_Homographe) von weiteren Beispielen:

- Aúgust, der (männlicher Vorname) und Augúst, der (Monat)
- Hochzeit, die (Vermählung; kurzes „o“) und Hochzeit, die (Höhepunkt; langes „o“)
- Essener, der: [ˈɛsənɐ] – Einwohner von Essen ./. [ɛˈseːnɐ] – Mitglied der jüdischen Sekte der Essener
- Heroin: [heroˈiːn] (das) – Droge ./. [heˈroːɪn] (die) – Heldin
- Konstanz: [ˈkɔnʃtants] – Stadt am Bodensee ./. [kɔnˈstants] (die) – Beständigkeit
- modern: [moˈdɛrn] – heutig, zeitgemäß (Adj.) ./. [ˈmoːdɐn] – faulen (Verb)
- übersetzen: [ˈyːbɐzɛtsən] – ans andere Ufer fahren ./. [yːbɐˈzɛtsən] – in eine andere Sprache übertragen
- umfahren: [ˈʊmfaːrən] – fahrend umstoßen ./. [ʊmˈfaːrən] – fahrend ausweichen
- Ténor, der (Grundhaltung) und Tenór, der (Stimmlage und Sänger)

Eine Präzisierung: Homographe werden auch Homogramme genannt und bezeichnen ein Wort aus einer Gruppe von Wörtern, die alle die gleiche Schreibweise, aber unterschiedliche Bedeutungen und häufig auch eine unterschiedliche Aussprache haben. Bei gleicher Aussprache ist es zugleich ein Homophon und somit ein Homonym.

Comment: Wobei hier ja leider unpassenderweise gleich einige Beispiele versammelt sind, in denen NICHT NUR die Betonung, sondern auch die Aussprache geändert werden muss, damit sich die Bedeutung ändert (z.B. Collagen) oder Begriffe, die in der deutschen Sprache doch eher selten bis nie verwendet werden (rentier für "Rentner"? Habe ich noch nie zuvor gehört)

Comment: @Augenfeind guter Einwand! Ich werde die Liste anpassen.

Comment: @Augenfeind: Ob sich aber meine Einkünfte aus der Vermietung von Rentieren rentieren werden?

Comment: OK, der Unterschied mit kurz vs lang gilt nicht, finde ich; und humor kleingeschrieben kenne ich leider gar nicht ... übrig bleiben *modern*, *August* und *Tenor* und natürlich mein schönes *umfahren*. Dann sind es ja wirklich ein paar – aber immer noch wenig.

Comment: Okay, ich habe den Humor aus dem Beitrag entfernt und u. a. mit Heroin ersetzt. ;-)

Comment: Vom Wortstamm würden aber die Heroin und das Heroin, das ü/Übersetzen sowie die Hochzeiten auf das gleiche zurückgehen.

Comment: @user_unknown ja, aber das spielt laut Fragestellung keine Rolle.

Comment: + (weg und Weg)

Comment: @bot47: Da ist die _Betonung_ aber gleich. @splattne: Die Hochzeit ist auch keine Frage der Betonung sondern der Vokallänge.

Comment: die Heroin gibt's wohl nicht. Ich meine, es kann nur Heroine heißen.

Comment: ähnlich wie 'übersetzen' auch 'überholen' (Fährmann, hol über). @HendrikVogt: `Ich fahre weg, auf dem Weg` - gleiche Betonung? Gehört die Dehnung des Vokals nicht zur Betonung?

Comment: @user: Ich bin kein Linguist, aber wäre ich einer, so würde ich mich freuen, wenn es für die verschiedenen Phänomene Betonung und Vokallänge auch unterschiedliche Begriffe gibt. Wikipedia ist zwar vielleicht nicht 100% überzeugend, aber [scheint meine Ansicht zu stützen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph#Unterschiedliche_Betonung_und_Vokall.C3.A4nge).

Comment: Die genannten Beispiele in einen Topf zu werfen, finde ich gewagt. Denn inhaltlich haben manche tatsächlich miteinander zu tun. Warum heißt der Monat August wohl so? Hochzeit kommt auch daher, dass es eben genau das ist: Ein Höhepunkt im Leben. Außerdem wird in dem Beispiel die Aussprache geändert, nicht nur die Betonung.

Dagegen ist úmfahren tatsächlich ein völlig anderes Wort als umfáhren, noch dazu mit gegensätzlicher Betonung.

Answer (score 5):

Die [von splattne genannten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/welche-deutschen-w%C3%B6rter-unterscheiden-sich-nur-in-der-betonung/1459#1459) *übersetzen* und *umfahren* sind Vertreter einer ganzen Gruppe von Wortpaaren, die sich jeweils nur durch Betonung und Bedeutung unterscheiden: nämlich Verben, die sowohl trennbar als auch untrennbar sein können. Diese Verben sind trennbar, wenn sie auf der ersten Silbe betont werden, und untrennbar (mit jeweils anderer Bedeutung), wenn sie auf einer anderen Silbe betont werden. Sie wurden bereits behandelt in [Wie kann man wissen, ob ein Verb trennbar ist?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/160/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-ein-verb-trennbar-ist). Neulich gab es ein Duplikat dieser Frage mit weiteren Vertretern dieser Gruppe: [Verbs that are both separable and inseparable](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/verbs-that-are-both-separable-and-inseparable)

Auf [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Homographe) gibt es noch eine längere Liste deutscher Homographe, die allerdings neben reinen Betonungsänderungen auch viel Fälle umfasst, in denen sich die Aussprache ändert.