# Zusammenschreiben von Infinitiv mit zu

Tags: verb, infinitive, compound

Eigentlich sollte die Sache recht einfach sein. Laut Duden werden die Erweiterungen mit zu zusammengeschrieben, wenn auch die Grundform zusammengeschrieben wird:
http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/infinitiv-mit-zu

Jetzt habe ich einen Text korrigiert und meine Rechtschreibkorrektur markiert „durchzuwühlen“ als falsch. Intuitiv hätte ich es auch getrennt geschrieben.

„Herauszureißen“ und „auszubrechen“ werden als korrekt erkannt.

So ganz verstehe ich das nicht. „Durchwühlen“ ist doch auch eine zusammengeschriebene Grundform. Den einzigen Unterschied, den ich erkenne, ist dass „durchwühlen“ ein schwaches Verb ist und die anderen beiden stark sind. Davon wird aber in der Regel im Duden nichts erwähnt.

**EDIT**

Um die bisherigen Erkenntnisse zusammenzufassen: (Jetzt fallen mir die Infinitiv + zu Wörter überall auf)

Bei Verben, die nicht trennbar sind, bleibt das „zu“ draußen: zu unterbinden (NICHT unterzubinden)

Infinitiv mit „zu“ erweitert wird zusammengeschrieben, wenn die Grundform eines trennbaren Verbs auch zusammengeschrieben wird.

Ob ein Verb trennbar ist, kann man anscheinend daran erkennen (als Daumenregel), dass die Betonung auf dem Präfix liegt.

Wird die Grundform getrennt geschrieben, wird die Erweiterung mit „zu“ in drei Worten geschrieben.

Mir ist aber noch nicht ganz klar, wann ein Wort nun trennbar ist. Die Regel klingt soweit klar; aber als ich vorhin „durchzuarbeiten“ in die Tastatur geklopft habe, wurde auch das rot markiert.
Laut Duden gibt es das Wort so, und wenn ich mich nicht täusche, bedeutet der Punkt, dass die Betonung auf „durch“ liegt (wird auch eindeutig so gesprochen).
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/durcharbeiten_durcharbeiten_trennbar

Ist die Betonungsregel vielleicht nicht korrekt/genau genug?
Ändert sich die Bedeutung von „durcharbeiten“ nicht, wenn man es getrennt verändert?

> Durch Arbeiten wird man nicht reich.
>   Den Text werde ich heute Abend durcharbeiten.

Oder hab ich das mit dem Trennen falsch verstanden? Im Duden gibt es auch folgenden Beispielsatz:

> Arbeiten Sie den Teig kräftig durch.

Sorry, dass ich das noch mal aufrolle; aber ich bin jetzt noch verwirrter als vorher.

Comment: Bevor Du eine Antwort akzeptierst lohnt es sich vielleicht noch etwas zuzuwarten (wie der Österreicher, glaube ich, zu sagen pflegt).

Comment: Naja, die Antwort von Mac mit den Kommentaren ergeben durchaus ein verständliches Bild. Was soll da noch kommen?

Comment: Es ging mir nur darum das Wort `zuzuwarten` unterzubringen.

Comment: Um mich endgültig zu verwirren, steht in dieser Presseaussendung von Duden "durchzuarbeiten" http://www.duden.de/presse/neuerscheinung--150-textaufgaben-5-bis-10-klasse

Comment: Lol, die Verwirrung ist verständlich, aber gerade bei solchen nicht ganz leicht zu entwirrenden Problemfällen sollte man sich *auf keinen Fall* auf eine automatische Rechtschreibprüfung verlassen.

Comment: Versuchs mal in zwei Etappen, die Trennbarkeit hat nämlich eigentlich mit der Zusammen-/Getrenntscheibung des Inf. mit zu eigentlich gar nix zu tun: Es gibt trennbare und nicht trennbare Verben. Nur bei ersteren stellt sich die Frage nach der Zusammen-/Getrenntschreibung, weil hier das "zu" in der Mitte steht. Ich hab mal versucht, das in meiner Antwort zu ergänzen.

Comment: Mögliches Duplikat: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/zusammen-oder-getrennt-schreiben-von-durchzusprechen (zumindest würde die Antwort da auch hier hin passen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK ich glaube, so lässt sich das eindeutig beantworten:

Mit "zu" erweiterter Infinitiv und Zusammenschreibung:

1. Bei Verben, die nicht trennbar sind, bleibt das "zu" draußen; das Verb wird immer zusammengeschrieben:

   *zu unterbinden (NICHT unterzubinden)*
2. Wird die Grundform eines trennbaren Verbs zusammengeschrieben, wird auch die mit "zu" erweiterte Konstruktion zusammengeschrieben.

   *durchzuarbeiten*
3. Wird die Grundform eines trennbaren Verbs getrennt geschrieben, wird die Erweiterung mit "zu" in drei Worten geschrieben.

Ob ein Verb trennbar ist, dafür gibt es ein paar Regeln:
http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K47

Für diese Frage wichtige Regeln:

> Regel 50:
>
> Bei bestimmten Zusammensetzungen aus Adverb oder Präposition + Verb
>   zeigt die Betonung, ob es sich um ein trennbares oder untrennbares
>   Verb handelt <§ 33 (3)>.
>
> - dụrchlaufen (trennbar: sie lief vorhin hier durch)
> - durchlaufen (nicht trennbar: das Projekt durchlief verschiedene Stadien)
> - übersetzen  (trennbar: der Fährmann setzte über)
> - übersẹtzen (nicht trennbar: sie übersetzte den Brief ins Deutsche)

Ein weiterer Beweis für Trennbarkeit ist, wenn man die Reihenfolge der Bestandteile in Abhängigkeit ihrer Stellung im Satz wechselt:

```
Du solltest nicht die ganze Nacht durcharbeiten.
Arbeite nicht die ganze Nacht durch.
```

Laut Duden ist es *dụrcharbeiten*. Also die Grundform wird zusammengeschrieben, Betonung liegt auf der Präposition und damit trennbar, ergo muss es "durchzuarbeiten" heißen, auch wenn meine Rechtschreibprüfung noch so vehement protestiert.

Für "durchwühlen" gibt es zwei Varianten mit leicht unterschiedlicher Bedeutung, wobei eines trennbar, das andere untrennbar ist.

"ausbrechen" ist trennbar und wird zu "auszubrechen", "ausreißen" zu "auszureißen".

PS: Sogar die URL verrät, dass "durcharbeiten" trennbar ist:
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/durcharbeiten_durcharbeiten_trennbar

Answer (score 7):

Es müsste sogar ganz anders heißen: „zu durchwühlen“

Durchwühlen ist ein nicht trennbares Verb (daran zu erkennen, dass das Präfix nicht betont wird) <sup>[Quelle](http://deutsch.lingo4u.de/grammatik/verben/trennbare)</sup>, es wird also in allen Flexionsformen und Konstruktionen zusammengeschrieben – auch beim Infinitiv mit zu.

**Edit**

Am besten stellt man sich zwei Fragen:

1. Ist das Verb trennbar?
   Wenn nicht (Verbstamm betont), bleibt
   das „zu“ sowieso außen vor und die Sache ist erledigt.
   Wenn ja (Präfix betont), stellt sich die zweite Frage:
2. Schreibt man das Verb in der Grundform zusammen?
   Wenn nicht,
   macht man’s mit dem „zu“ genauso.
   Wenn ja, macht man’s mit dem „zu“
   genauso.

Die Rechtschreibprüfung kann man in diesem Zusammenhang in der Regel vergessen, weil sie zum einen bereits an Frage 1) scheitert und zum anderen wohl nur schwer erkennen kann, ob es im Satzzusammenhang z. B. darum geht, eine *Maßnahme* **durchzuführen** oder – etwa im Fall einer *Ausstellung* – jemanden **durch zu führen**. (Bei diesem Beispiel kommt nämlich noch erschwerend hinzu, dass der zweite Fall überhaupt nix mit „durchführen“ zu tun hat.) Die Rechtschreibprüfung stößt also immer wieder an Grenzen, mit denen bisher nur ein menschlicher Korrektor zurechtkommt.

Comment: noch eine Quelle: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/160/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-ein-verb-trennbar-ist ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Lol, richtig: warum in die Ferne schweifen... +1 :)

Comment: Hm OK. Das ist etwas verwirrend für mich, denn "durch zu wühlen" kommt mir auch sehr vertraut vor, ist vielleicht Umgangssprache/Dialekt. Auch bezüglich der Betonung bin ich mir nicht sicher, aber laut Duden ist die Betonung auch wirklich nicht auf dem ersten Wort:
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/durchwuehlen_aufwuehlen_absuchen

Jedoch gibt es scheinbar auch ein durchwühlen mit Betonung weiter vorne:
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/durchwuehlen_durchgraben_durchsuchen

Comment: Ah, die Variante mit dem betonten Präfix kenne ich jetzt wieder nicht... Klingt für mich so, als ob da eben der "durch"-Aspekt betont werden soll: Wie im Duden-Beispiel, wo sich die Maus "durchwühlt", analog zu "sich durchkämpfen", "sich durchbeißen" etc. Wahrscheinlich nicht zufällig alles Reflexivkonstruktionen. Bei "durchsuchen" haben wir übrigens den gleichen Fall: der Duden bietet beide Varianten an und auch hier ist die Bedeutung leicht unterschiedlich, jeweils passend zum betonten Wortteil.

Comment: Siehe auch der Dauer-Fahrlehrer-Witz: "Sie sollen den Polizisten umfahren, nicht umfahren!", in der Vergangenheit dann "Ich bat Sie, den Polizisten zu umfahren, nicht umzufahren." Wobei ich hier jetzt auch nicht sicher bin, ob "umzufahren" zusammengeschrieben (argh!) richtig ist.

Comment: OK, das macht soweit alles Sinn. Aber wenn die zweite Variante von durchwühlen trennbar ist und in der Grundform zusammen geschrieben wird, dann müsste die um "zu" erweiterte Form auch zusammen geschrieben werden. Wird sie aber nicht. 0.o Ist "durch zu wühlen" damit dann auch komplett falsch oder wieder etwas anderes?

Comment: Ah - jetzt kommen wir der Sache näher... Ich fürchte, dass die Lösung ganz einfach ist: Dein Rechtschreibprogramm kennt die trennbare Version von durchwühlen nicht und streicht Dir "durchzuwühlen" natürlich an. "durch zu wühlen" fällt ihm einfach nicht auf, weil es das als drei isolierte Wörter behandelt - das bedeutet nicht, dass der Ausdruck insgesamt so richtig wäre (die Textprüfung auf Duden.de streicht das z.B. sofort an).