# Zusammen oder getrennt Schreiben von "durchzusprechen"?

Tags: compound

Bei Wörtern die mit "zu" oder "ge" verbunden werden, komme ich immer durcheinander und weiß nicht nach welcher Regel ich sie schreiben muss. Werden sie zusammen geschrieben oder auseinander?

*Beispiel:*

> Ich würde mich gerne mal mit Dir zusammensetzen um Deinen Entwurf **durchzusprechen**.

oder

> Ich würde mich gerne mal mit Dir zusammensetzen um Deinen Entwurf **durch zu sprechen**.

Nach welcher Regel funktioniert das?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Diese Grundregel hilft in den meisten Fällen schon viel:

Wenn das Verb in der Grundform (also ohne »zu«) zusammengeschrieben wird, schreibt man auch den Infinitiv mit »zu« zusammen:

> **aufgeben:** Ich habe einen Brief aufzugeben.
>   **teilnehmen:** Iris lud Hans ein an der Feier teilzunehmen.
>   **forttragen:** Walter bat seine Tochter den Müll fortzutragen.

Wird die Grundform nicht zusammen geschrieben, so gilt das auch für die abgeleitete Form:

> **Rad fahren:** Lisa hat nicht gelernt Rad zu fahren.
>   **getrennt schreiben:** Es ist nicht sinnvoll, immer alles getrennt zu schreiben.
>   **sitzen bleiben:** Philipp schafft es nicht still sitzen zu bleiben.

Dein konkreter Fall ist aber komplizierter. Hier geht es nämlich nicht darum, ob »durchsprechen« oder »durch sprechen« richtig ist (richtig ist die zusammen geschriebene Form). Sondern es hängt davon ab, ob die beiden Bestandteile trennbar sind oder nicht.

Hier haben wir es nämlich mit der Verbindung *Präposition + Verb* zu tun, und da gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten:

Wenn die Betonung auf der Präposition liegt, sind beide trennbar. Beispiele:

> **durchlaufen** Betonung auf »durch«: Hans wird vermutlich als Erster hier durchlaufen. Vergangenheit: Hans lief hier durch. (Falsch: "Hans durchlief hier")
>   **übersetzen** Betonung auf »über«: Charon wird mit seiner Fähre den Flus Styx übersetzen. Vergangenheit: Charon setzte über den Fluss. (Falsch: "Charon übersetzte den Fluss")

Der Infinitiv mit »zu« wird in diesen Fällen wie folgt gebildet:

> Von Hans wird erwartet, hier durchzulaufen.
>   Charon hat die Aufgabe, mit der Fähre überzusetzen.

Liegt die Betonung auf dem Verb, dann sind beide Teile untrennbar:

> **durchlaufen** Betonung auf »laufen«: Der Prozess muss fünf Schritte durchlaufen. Vergangenheit: Der Prozess durchlief fünf Schritte (Falsch: "Der Prozess lief fünf Schritte durch")
>   **übersetzen** Betonung auf »setzen«: Frau Mayer wird den Roman übersetzen. Vergangenheit: Sie übersetzte das Buch. (Falsch: "Sie setzte das Buch über")

Die beiden Teile kleben so fest aneinander, dass da nicht mal ein »zu« dazwischen geht:

> Der Prozess hatte fünf Schritte zu durchlaufen. (Falsch: "Der Prozess hatte fünf Schritte durchzulaufen.")
>   Frau Mayer wurde gebeten, das Buch zu übersetzen. (Falsch: »Frau Mayer wurde gebeten, das Buch überzusetzen.«)

**Auflösung deines Falls:**
Die Zusammensetzung besteht aus einer Präposition und einem Verb. Die Vergangenheit sieht so aus: »Wir sprachen den Entwurf durch«. Die Variante »Wir durchsprachen den Entwurf« ist falsch. Daher sind die beiden Teile trennbar, und die Silbe »zu« wird dazwischengeschoben:

> Ich würde mich gerne mal mit Dir zusammensetzen um Deinen Entwurf **duchzusprechen.**

Comment: _Charon setzte über den Fluss_: Das ist _setzen_ mit einem Präpositionalausdruck, nicht _übersetzen_. Sieht man unmittelbar an der Wortstellung, weil ein abgetrenntes Präfix weiter hinten stünde: _Charon setzt mit dem Kahn über._

Comment: Auch wenn das gewöhnungsbedürftig klingt, müsste es doch *Charon setzt über den Fluss über* heißen, wenn man *übersetzen* als Verb annimmt.

Comment: @fifaltra: Nein. Mit welcher Begründung sollte »über« zweimal im Satz erscheinen?

Comment: Weil es einmal eine Präposition ist und einmal zu dem Verb gehört. Vergleiche: Charon schwamm über den Fluss. Da ist es ja auch nicht das Verb * *überschwimmen*. Chirlu hat übrigens genau das gleiche gemeint.

Answer (score 1):

Die erste Variante ist die richtige. (Anscheinend bräuchte sie auch ein Komma). *Durchsprechen* ist ein trennbares Verb. Es bildet den *Infinitiv mit zu* wie folgt in diesem Beispiel:

> nach|vollziehen → nachzuvollziehen

Also:

> Ich würde mich gerne mal mit Dir zusammensetzen, um Deinen Entwurf **duchzusprechen**.

Comment: D.h. man muss es schon von Wort zu Wort unabhängig nachschauen, ja?