# vollbringen untrennbare Vorsilbe

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context

Warum fällt vollbringen in der Kategorie der Verben mit untrennbarer Vorsilbe ?

z.B.

> Die Anforderungen die an die Bewerber gestellt werden sind unterschiedlich, je nachdem, ob sie in > Aussicht haben, Wunder zu vollbringen oder nicht.

Was sind dann Regel (oder eine Liste von wichtigen Verben) für untrennbare Vorsilben?

Comment: Beantwortet das die Frage? [Wie kann man wissen, ob ein Verb trennbar ist?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/160/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-ein-verb-trennbar-ist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leider gibt es keine Regel, die einem einfach sagt, ob ein Verb trenn- oder untrennbar ist. Solltest du eine finden, wird sie mit großer Wahrscheinlickeit Ausnahmen haben. Der einfachste Beweis dafür sind viele Verben, die es sowohl in trennbarer als auch untrennbarer Form gibt und die dann auch unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben (z.B. um-fahren vs. umfahren).

Es wird dir wohl nichts anderes übrigbleiben, als jedes Verb zu lernen.

Nicht einmal alleine für das Präfix *voll-* könnte man sicher sagen, dass alle Verben, die damit beginnen, **untrennbar** wären:

untrennbar:

- vollbringen
- vollziehen
- vollenden
- vollführen

trennbar:

- vollkleckern
- sich vollessen
- vollladen
- vollpumpen
  ....

Möglicherweise ist es so, dass die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass dass Verb trennbar ist, größer wird, je *wörtlicher* das Präfix "voll" (als Gegenteil von "leer") bedeutet. Möglicherweise läßt sich das auch generalisieren: Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass ein Verb trennbar ist, steigt, wenn

1. Das Präfix ein eigenständiges Wort ist - wenn nicht, - z.B. *'be-'haupten*, *'ent-'haupten* ist das Verb sicher untrennbar.
2. Je 'wörtlicher' das Präfix genommen wird, um so größer ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass das Verb trennbar ist.